# MenuItem with IsCheckable property is always returning True for IsChecked

Tags: wpf, menuitem

I have a MenuItem where I set IsCheckable = True and a method that fires on the Click event that checks or unchecks the MenuItem.

```
<MenuItem x:Name="DebugWindowMenuItem" Header="Debug Window" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="False" Click="DebugWindow_Click" />
```

Then my C# code looks like this...

```
private void DebugWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine(DebugWindowMenuItem.IsChecked);

    if (DebugWindowMenuItem.IsChecked == true) {
        DebugWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        DebugWindowMenuItem.IsChecked = false;
    } else {
        DebugWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        DebugWindowMenuItem.IsChecked = true;
    }
}
```

I'm clearly missing something because the XAML states that it's not checked but the Console output says it is everytime I click DebugWindowMenuItem.

Is there another parameter I'm missing?

**UPDATE:** Basically, don't set IsChecked. Treat a checkable MenuItem as a CheckBox.

Comment: What is `DebugWindowMenuItem`? (Before you answer to this question, verify and double-check in the debugger that whatever you believe _DebugWindowMenuItem_ to be is really the reality.) From the code in your question it is not 100% certain that `DebugWindowMenuItem` is actually the MenuItem with the "Debug Window" header. Also, is the value changing/toggling if you repreatedly click / invoke the DebugWindow_Click handler, or will it stay `true` even when repeatedly invoking DebugWindow_Click?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally left the Name out of my post. It's in my code though. And the command is called each time I click that MenuItem. The code is called but the IsChecked status always returns True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you haven't thought about the inbuilt behaviour.

If you make a menuitem checkable like that.

What happens?

It acts like a checkbox.

What happens when you click a checkbox?

If you comment out your code so you have:

```
    private void DebugWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DebugWindowMenuItem.IsChecked);
    }
```

When you click it, the menu item gets a tick appears and ischecked becomes true.
Click it again and it becomes false.

Don't set Ischecked.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh... makes sense. That did it.